# Proof for Singularity of Additive Identity

Tags: alternative-proof

On page 19 of his [Calculus book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471000051), Apostol proves that $0$ is the only additive identity element for real numbers as follows:

> In fact, if $0$ and $0'$ both have this property ($x+0=x$, $x+0'=x$ for all $x$ --op)
>   , then ${0+0' = 0}$ and $0+0=0$. Hence, $0+0'=0+0$ and, by the cancellation law, $0=0'$.

The following, seemingly more immediate, proof occurred to me:

If the property is true for $0$ and $0'$, then $0+0' = 0$ but $0+0'=0'$ as well. Thus, ${0=0'}$.

Was Apostol's choice arbitrary, or am I missing something?

Comment: Apostol property seems to state that $0$ is a right-neutral element, while in your proof you use the property of being both-side neutral

Comment: Federica: Apostol assumes the Commutative law and treats $0$ as both-side neutral.

Comment: hence $0=0+0'=0'$

Comment: So is the alternative proof indeed valid?

Comment: i think absolutely valid

Comment: Strangely, Apostol seems to emphasize that the exclusivity of $0$ depends on the Cancellation Law.

Comment: Apostol is writing a textbook and so wants readers to understand the proof. If he/she simply wrote $0=0+0^{'}=0^{'}$ I suspect most readers would utter a sincere, "wtf"?

Comment: @user6981: I believe I was a bit more generous than that. Besides, Apostol isn't giving a better explanation of that proof; he's giving a different one.

Answer (score 1):

Let me just say that your proof is valid. There is rarely one way to write a proof; Apostol, I suspect, chose his method for pedagogical reasons.

Apostol is being *very careful* to use a proof, relying on the cancellation law, that can be generalized to noncommutative structures. In the case at hand, he is defining the field of real numbers, in which addition **is** commutative. And so the order of elements can be inverted, and hence your proof is entirely valid, in this particular situation. In a non-commutatitve structure, with a noncommutative binary operation $*$, it is ***not*** the case that for all $x, y$ in that structure, $x * y = y * x$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $0,0'$ both satisfying axiom 4 in Apostol book (existence of identity element). Then
$$0=0+0'$$
by axiom 4 applyed to $0'$. Then
$$0+0'=0'+0$$
by axiom 1 (commutative law). Finally
$$0'+0=0'$$
by axiom 4, now applyed to $0$.

The sentence "cancellation law shows unicity of neutral element" doesn't mean "cancellation law is the unique way to show that unicity"

Comment: I know he doesn't say explicitly say this is the only way to prove it, but he does repeatedly emphasize the dependence on the cancellation laws.
I just wanted confirmation that I wasn't missing something.

Comment: @IsaacKleinman The only thing i can suggest is that Apostol is defining the field of real numbers, whose additive structure is commutative, but in more general settings, in a non-abelian group, you can't invert the order of elements, but you certainly can still apply cancellation law

Answer (score 0):

Apostol is wrong.  If he wants to depend on the cancellation law, then just use it in the beginning.  That is, $x+0=x$ and $x+0_1=x$ so $x+0=x+0_1$ and therefore, by cancellation, $0=0_1$.

The way that you state the proof is correct.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! You should see  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to learn about mathjax- what we do to format math equations mathjax changes 1/2 to $\frac1{2}$